# xpath to get immediate following element

Tags: xpath

I'm writing xpath in "title" element want to get following "abbrev" within same parent(feature). I'm using xpath 1.0

```
<root>
<feature>
    <title>Burst Cycle Length</title>
    <titlealts class="- topic/titlealts ">
        <navtitle>Burst Cycle Length</navtitle>
    </titlealts>
    <abbrv>BCL</abbrv>
    <featbody/>
</feature>
<feature>
    <title>Burst Parameter</title>
    <titlealts class="- topic/titlealts ">
        <navtitle>Burst Cycle Length</navtitle>
    </titlealts>
    <abbrv>BCP</abbrv>
    <featbody/>
</feature>
</root>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to search through XPath? Didnt get your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all nodes:

```
/root/feature/title/following-sibling::abbrv
```

Or, if you want a specific one:

```
/root/feature/title[.='Burst Cycle Length']/following-sibling::abbrv
```

This has the same output as the preceding:

```
/root/feature[1]/title/following-sibling::abbrv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first "abbrv" node that has same parent with current "title" node

```
following-sibling::node()[name() ='abbrv'][1]
```

and this will get a list of "abbrv"

```
following-sibling::node()[name() ='abbrv']
```